# Cannot see a field added on a JSON document with Nodejs and Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

if I query MongoDB with a simple query like this using mongoose:

```
User
.find()
.where('address.loc').near({ center: [lat,lng], maxDistance: 1 })
.exec(function(err, result) {

  if (err) {
    request.log(['server', 'database', 'error'], 'An error occured during the execution of the query');
  }else{
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;++i){
      result[i]["distance"] = 5;
    }
    console.log(result[0].distance);
    console.log(result[0])
  }

});
```

The first console.log prints : 5

But the second one prints :

`{ address: { loc: [ 37.0814402, 15.287517 ], value: 'viale tica' },
  tags: [ 'Primi', 'Secondi' ],
  __v: 0,
  cap: 96100,
  ad_number: 15,
  business_email: 'prova@provbhifbvvyvg',
  _id: 571b3b78249a2e160b4eee3f }`

Why this document and the others in the result array are without the field distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `result[0]` is a mongoose document object. And when you call `console.log(result[0])` the result is converted to the string (with mongoose document `toString` function). But mongoose document doesn't contain `distance` field.

To do what you want, you should convert each document to object:

```
var objects = results.forEach(results, function(res) {
  res = res.toObject();
  res["distance"] = 5;
  return res;
});
console.log(objects[0].distance);
console.log(objects[0]);
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about mongoose object.